# Android bitmaps in xml leak memory?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, resources, bitmap, drawable

Here are some newbie memory management observations to which I would like 
hear an experienced opinion.

It seems that setting android:backgound="@drawable/xyz" in a xml
layout causes memory loss in my app. The respective activities keep
stacking up until I get an OOM error. This is especially true if I rotate
the device orientation.

However, if I load the same resource with setBackgoundResource(), and then clear the
callback and set the background reference to null, there is no leak whatsoever.

that is, first in onCreate()

```
    mMainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_general_android);
```

and then in onDestroy()

```
mMainLayout.getBackground().setCallback(null);
mMainLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Is this roughly correct, or am I missing something essential?

Comment: I do face very same problem time to time. I will try to manage bitmap in onCrate and onDestroy. ty

Answer (score 1):

This would only happen if you keep a copy of the drawables in a static cache for instance. You might also be leaking your activities and setting the drawables to null simply hides the problem for a little longer. You should use a tool like MAT to inspect the content of your heap and figure out what's going on.

Comment: The observation above is based on a long and painful weekend with MAT :) Essentially I made barebone linear layout with nothing but 500 k background resource bitmap, and an activity that did nothing but loaded the xml with setContentView(). When the bitmap was set inside xml => memory loss and OOM. When loaded programmatically and cleared in onDestroy(), no problems. However, I should mention that the rest of the app, outside this minimal test activity, is rather large, which may affect the results. I specifically wanted to test it in "inside real app". Android version is 2.2 (level 8).